# MBP 2012 No Battery Available, Your Computer is not connected to a power source

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

I have a MBP2012 with a failing battery. Battery shows about 3V across my multimeter on the but the port is still 12v at the correct pin points. So the battery is dead - that's fine, I can replace it. Apple Diagnostics boot doesn't tell me anything is wrong.

I have reset the nvram and smc a few times.

I have clean installed Mac OS 10.11.6. The installer (and any software update screens) all think think that I'm not connected to a power source.

[image]

after macos was installed I took screenshots of the battery menu and system summary.

Macos thinks I'm using the battery that it acknowledges isn't there.

[image]

but the battery shows up under the system report...

[image]

Is this normal behaviour for a mac with a failing battery or does it hint at a problem further into the machine? I'd replace the battery if it will fix the problem.

Comment: Its quite common for macOS to get confused when the battery isn't present or doesn't respond correctly. Replacing it should fix the issue. I presume you've checked the power adapter?

Comment: Yep the adaptor is fine. I'll replace the battery then.